# How can I extract email addresses from emails on Office 365?

Tags: outlook.com, export, contacts, office-365

I need to create a list of email addresses of those I've been emailing and who have been emailing me via my office 365 email account.

If it were a hundred or so people then I'd just do it by hand (make a contact for each one, then export the contact list), but I have thousands of people I've been in contact with that I need to record. I do have access to the admin panel on office 365 if needed.

What is the easiest method for me to extract a list of email addresses from my email itself, including email recipients for emails I've sent, and email senders for emails I've received?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reasonably up-to-date version of Office, the easiest method is to use Excel with PowerQuery.

PowerQuery has a source for Office 365 and Exchange Online. Connect up to the Mail entry and you can access all the From, To, CC and BCC entries. Takes a bit of wrangling but it is all point and click. No programming.

Comment: Hi @Julian Knight would you know of a link or tutorial which can do the same?

Comment: @manishKungwani, I searched for "powerquery example exchange online" and it came back with this as the 1st entry (lots of others to choose from as well): https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/analyzing-your-microsoft-exchange-account-data-with-power-query/